# Calling Ethereum Smart contract function inside a JS loop is not synchronize

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ethereum, solidity

I have a smart contract which has the function returns some values based on the stored data. The function is defiend as below

```
 function getPaperValues(uint _paperId) public view returns(string memory title,string memory ipfscid,address author,PaperStatus status,address[] memory reviewers,bytes32[] memory keywords,uint version)
{
    return (paperFiles[_paperId].title,paperFiles[_paperId].ipfs_cid,paperFiles[_paperId].author,paperFiles[_paperId].status,paperFiles[_paperId].reviewers,paperFiles[_paperId].keywords, paperFiles[_paperId].version_number);
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I call it through javascript but I have a situation where I have to call this function inside the javascript under a for loop. The problem is the parameter which is **"index"** when I provide this to **paperContractObj.getPaperValues** it returns me correct values from the blockchain but the parameter **"Index"** value gets changed. It seems like the function is not properly synchronized with its call time and result time.

```
                for (loop = 0; loop < result.length-1; loop++)
                {

                    var index = result[loop];
                    // this function takes index and return correct values as per associated index
                    paperContractObj.getPaperValues(index,{from:account},function (err, result2) {

                    // On this line index value shows different values even though result I received inside result2 is associated with the correct index.  

                    console.log("loop: -"+index); //need to fix this part loop id not coming properly it shows 

                        if (err) {
                            console.log("CALL-ERROR-REASON: "+JSON.stringify(err));
                            console.log("REASON: Unable to retrieve Paper values by Ids");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("CALL-SUCCESS: "+JSON.stringify(result2));
                            console.log("CALL-ACHIEVE: Recieved current papers values via ids successfully"+result[loop]);
                            addListHtmlDivs(result2,index); 
                            // Here values from the chain is coming fine but index which was provided as a parameter to this function is changed or different

                        }
     });

                }
```

How can I make sure the parameter inside this contract function do not get changed due to the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved using a constant index within the loop

```
for (loop = 0; loop < result.length-1; loop++)
{

                    const index = result[loop];
```

using const will give the correct value even inside the event-based result of contract function call.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to call asynchronously the contract function.

Just put

> await

before your function call

> paperContractObj.getPaperValues

Comment: does not work since my function is not async, and after making it to async it did not work.

Comment: what error do you get? It's a matter of making the function async now. once this is sorted the code will have the behavior you were expecting